Angular Dynamically Add Form Controls to Form
My goal is to be able to add a search form with any number of filters on a given page.  For example, on my HomePageComponent, I would like to be able to do:
<app-search-form>
  <app-searchbox></app-searchbox>
</app-search-form>

Right now, my SearchFormComponent is:
html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, SearchboxComponent],
  templateUrl: './search-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './search-form.component.css'
})
export class SearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }

  search() {
    console.log('Searching...');
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}

SearchboxComponent is:
html
<label for="searchbox">Search:</label>
<input id="searchbox" formControlName="searchbox" type="text" />

ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchbox',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './searchbox.component.html',
  styleUrl: './searchbox.component.css',
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useFactory: () => inject(ControlContainer, { skipSelf: true }) }]
})
export class SearchboxComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
    this.formGroup.addControl("searchbox", new FormControl('', null));
  }
}

Possible future components like SearchCategoryFilterComponent and SearchLocationFilterComponent could be added and if the given page wanted those to be in the form, they could just be added within the <app-search-form>.
With the way I currently have it setup, I get the error: NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ControlContainer!  I think that is because when <app-searchbox></app-searchbox> is added in HomePageComponent, instead of it seeing the SearchFormComponent as its parent and being able to inject the ControlContainer, it sees HomePageComponent as the parent, which does not have a form.  If I move <app-searchbox></app-searchbox> to be within the SearchFormComponent's <form> the UI and form submission works as desired.
How can I get this so that HomePageComponent is able to dictate what is in the form?  Allowing it to add the filters not only allows each page to have different filters, but it also allows each page to add styling to each filter.

You cannot do this, because when you use content projection, the content that you want to project in the child, is actually initialized on the parent level, since there is no form on the parent level, there is no ControlContainer hence the error.

To solve this you can implement rendering dynamic components using *ngComponentOutlet of ng-container.
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="formComponent"></ng-container>
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

We pass the component you want to initialize as an @Input.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SearchFormComponent, SearchboxComponent],
  template: `
    <app-search-form [formComponent]="component">
    </app-search-form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  component = SearchboxComponent;
}


Full Code:
import { Component, inject, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ControlContainer,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchbox',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <label for="searchbox">Search:</label>
    <input id="searchbox" formControlName="searchbox" type="text" />
  `,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: () => inject(ControlContainer, { skipSelf: true }),
    },
  ],
})
export class SearchboxComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
    this.formGroup.addControl('searchbox', new FormControl('', null));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, SearchboxComponent, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="search()">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="formComponent"></ng-container>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  `,
})
export class SearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formComponent: any;
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }

  search() {
    console.log('Searching...');
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SearchFormComponent, SearchboxComponent],
  template: `
    <app-search-form [formComponent]="component">
    </app-search-form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  component = SearchboxComponent;
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


Stackblitz Demo

I figured that was the issue.  The problem with doing it this way is that HomePageComponent cannot add styling or other html around each filter.  If I go this route, I'd rather just have all of the filters listed in the SearchForm and just have attributes to enable them and to pass styling to each.  I would like to be able to do something as custom as <app-search-form><fieldset><app-searchbox /></fieldset><h1>Other Filters</h1><fieldset><app-search-category-filter /> <br /> <app-search-location-filter /></fieldset></app-search-form>.

@ScubaSteve Why dont you create a wrapper component with all the extra fitting html and pass that component as an input instead? since angular has little flexibility here?

So, you're saying each instance of the search form would create a component that had all of the filters it wanted with the html and styling it wanted around each, then pass that component into the SearchForm like you have in the example?  If so, I guess that works, but from the perspective of consumer of this reusable search, that seems odd and not intuitive.  I don't discount it as it does resolve the problem, but not in the way I would want use it throughout a system.

@ScubaSteve If you can't find an alternative, this is the solution
